# table Teacher has nocolumn named First_Name... when inserting values to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am getting the following error when attempting to insert a row containing the user information of a user type "teacher".  I believe that the error has something to do with the insert in the addTeacher() method in the TeacherDAOtest class as this is of value -1 . i cannot however work out why. please may you help me to solve this?

logcat gives the following errors:

> 12-17 22:02:46.896: I/System.out(669): CREATE TABLE Teacher(User_ID
>   TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,First_Name TEXT NOT NULL,SurName TEXT NOT
>   NULL); 
>   12-17 22:02:46.896: E/SQLiteLog(669): (1) table Teacher has nocolumn named First_Name 
>   12-17 22:02:46.936: E/SQLiteDatabase(669):Error inserting First_Name=help User_ID=hepl220246 SurName=please
>   12-17 22:02:46.936: E/SQLiteDatabase(669):android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Teacher has no columnnamed First_Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Teacher(First_Name,User_ID,SurName) VALUES (?,?,?) 
>   12-17 22:02:46.936:E/SQLiteDatabase(669):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) 
>   ...
>
> 22:02:46.936: E/SQLiteDatabase(669):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   12-17 22:02:46.946:E/SQLiteLog(669): (1) no such column: User_ID 
>   12-17 22:02:46.946:D/AndroidRuntime(669): Shutting down VM 
>   12-17 22:02:46.946:W/dalvikvm(669): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300) 
>   12-17 22:02:46.986: E/AndroidRuntime(669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
>   12-17 22:02:46.986: E/AndroidRuntime(669): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: User_ID (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT User_ID, First_Name, SurName FROM
>   Teacher WHERE User_ID = -1 
>   12-17 22:02:46.986: E/AndroidRuntime(669):
>   ...

SQL code in the helper class looks like this:

```
   public static final String USER_ID = "User_ID";
    public static final String FNAME = "First_Name";
    public static final String SNAME = "SurName"; 
    public static final String TABLE_TEACHER = "Teacher";

public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TEACHER = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_TEACHER+"("
            +USER_ID +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"  
            +FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            +SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL"
            +");";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TEACHER);
    }
```

This is the model class minus the method that creates a user Id for the user, i believe that this is not the source of my problems, but you might want to see it just in case:
*EDIT: the getters and setters for the top 3 private methods are also not pasted below, but follow the usual convention.

```
public class RegisterTeacherActivity extends Activity {
    EditText firstNameInput;
    EditText surnameInput;
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String userID;
    private String teacherID;
    Button registerTeacherBtn;
    Context ctx = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_teacher);
        firstNameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teacherFname);
        surnameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teacherSname);
        registerTeacherBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerTeacherBtn);
        registerTeacherBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                firstName = firstNameInput.getText().toString();
                surname = surnameInput.getText().toString();
                teacherID = createUserID(firstName, surname);
                TeacherDAOtest newTeacher = new TeacherDAOtest(ctx);
                newTeacher.addTeacher(teacherID, firstName, surname);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration Sucessful \n your userID is: ".concat(teacherID) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

this is the dao class:

```
public class TeacherDAOtest {

    public static final String TAG = "TeacherDAOtest";

        // Database fields
        private SQLiteDatabase test;
        private DBHelperTest dbHelper;
        private Context context;
        private String[] allColumns = { DBHelperTest.USER_ID, DBHelperTest.FNAME,
                DBHelperTest.SNAME};

        public TeacherDAOtest(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            dbHelper = new DBHelperTest(context);
            // open the database
            try {
                open();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SQLException on opening database " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
                d.setTitle(TAG + " database failed to open");
                TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                tv.setText(TAG + " database failed to open");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
        public void open() throws SQLException {
            this.test = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
        }

        protected RegisterTeacherActivity cursorToTeacher(Cursor cursor){
            RegisterTeacherActivity teacher = new RegisterTeacherActivity(); 
            teacher.setUserID(cursor.getString(0));
            teacher.setFirstName(cursor.getString(1));
            teacher.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));
            return teacher;
        }

        public RegisterTeacherActivity addTeacher(String userID, String firstName, String lastName) { 
            System.out.println(DBHelperTest.SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TEACHER);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBHelperTest.USER_ID, userID);
            values.put(DBHelperTest.FNAME, firstName);
            values.put(DBHelperTest.SNAME, lastName);
            long insertID = this.test.insert(
                    DBHelperTest.TABLE_TEACHER, null, values);
            Cursor cursor = this.test.query(DBHelperTest.TABLE_TEACHER, allColumns,
                    DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " = " + insertID, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            RegisterTeacherActivity newTeacher = cursorToTeacher(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newTeacher;
        }
```

Comment: uninstall and then install your app and see if it works

Comment: Incase you have changed schema during dev time, you can clear the data from settings or uninstall and install once.. If the scema change is across commercial versions(not during development), please make sure that upgrade logic is written correctly.

Comment: thanks guys, its currently running on the eclipse emulator, as opposed to installed on an actual device. is there an equivalent method i could try?

Comment: also im building for android 4.1 . is there any further information/code that i could provide that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both errors are now solved.

I realised that i had some erroneous code at the end of my addTeacher() method.
This method has now been changed to void and has has been simplified.

```
public void addTeacher(String userID, String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println(DBHelperTest.SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TEACHER);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelperTest.USER_ID, userID);
        values.put(DBHelperTest.FNAME, firstName);
        values.put(DBHelperTest.SNAME, lastName);
        test.insert(DBHelperTest.TABLE_TEACHER, null, values);
    }
```

The above solved the fatal exception that crashed my app.

The second issue was that insert in the DAO class was equal to -1. 
This was solved for reasons beyond my comprehension by changing the name of the database. 
insert is now equal to 3 and rows are being inserted correctly.

Thank you for your comments